# Blender problem UV texture after applied subdivision surface

Tags: uv, subdivision-surface

[image]

[image]

Can someone help me to fix this UV texture please ? Thank you. The texture should be like first image after I applied smooth in Subdivision Surface in Modifier. Thank you for any helps !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like part of your mesh isn't unwrapped and the subdivision modifier streches that part out.

But maybe the newly created geometry is dragged around your entire UV Map similar to this: [image: UV]
In that case try separating part of your leaf using P and then joining both objects again by selecting both in Object Mode and pressing CTRL + J

Comment: It worked for my leaf Thank you !